# ¿Cómo permitir el acceso sólo por dominio?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

Me gustaría saber como puedo permitir el acceso a mi servidor sólo por dominio, es decir, que no se pueda acceder a mi servidor mediante la ip publica, que sólo se pueda acceder mediante un dominio que apunte a mi IP.

He estado realizando varias pruebas, pero no consigo este tipo de filtro, solo consigo el prohibir o permitir el acceso a una única IP.

Comment: Te recomiendo le heches un vistazo a la siguiente respuesta que se encuentra en SO en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34706993/5520161

Comment: Llegaste a probar lo que sugieren en la respuesta marcada como válida en este post? Hace tiempo cuando utilizaba el servicio VPS de un proveedor X, esa llegó a ser mi solución para evitar el acceso vía IP... Ahora que me manejo con DO me manejo mas rápidamente...

--> https://serverfault.com/questions/607137/restrict-direct-ip-access-to-website

Answer (score 1):

Existen demasiadas formas de hacerlo.

1. Para **bloquear** las conexiones que usan el IP en vez del nombre, esto va en el `.conf` de Apache (hay que reiniciar):

   ```py
   <VirtualHost tudominio.com:80>
       ServerName tudominio.com
       ServerAdmin webmaster@tudominio.com
       UseCanonicalName Off
       <If "tolower(%{SERVER_NAME}) != 'tudominio.com'">
           AllowOverride None
           Require all denied
       </If>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

2. Ya que estás preguntando cómo hacerlo desde el .htaccess, esta es otra forma:

   ```py
   RewriteEngine On

   # Si  NO  está accediendo a este dominio
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?tudominio\.com$ [NC]
   # Mostrarle un 403 Forbidden
   RewriteRule "" - [F]
   ```

3. Alternativamente, pordrías redireccionar desde el IP al host:.

   ```py
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?tudominio\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule (.*) http://tudominio.com/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```

Comment: La condicion del dominio sería, subdominio.dominio.es, he probado con tu código, pero no hace nada, no da error, pero no me echa con la IP. Lo he puesto así, RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.dom\.es$ [NC]

Comment: Dado que desde el .htaccess no hay manera de hacerlo, como se haría desde el conf?

Comment: @Diego desde el .htaccess sí se puede, como respondí. El problema será que no tenés habilitado el uso con AllowOverride o alguna otra configuración que entra en conflicto... Agregué más información en la respuesta de como hacerlo desde el `<VirtualHost>` en el .conf.